# Прозрачность для объекта (изображения)

Tags: html, css, css3, изображения, google-chrome

Необходимо придать картинке 100% прозрачность определенной формы.
Для Google Chrome использую

```
-webkit-mask-image : url("/img/maska4slider.png");
mask : url(#mask)
```

Пробую добавить для Firefox

```
-ms-mask : url("/img/maska4slider.png");
```

Вот только не получается. Что бы было понятнее, вот страница, на которой пытаюсь это реализовать: [ссылка](http://alisa.web-apple.ru/alisa/core/)
Резать картинки - это слишком просто и неправильно,т.к. картинки будут загружаться из админки.

Comment: Нестандартное свойство `-webkit-mask-image` поддерживается только в браузерах на движках Chromium/Blink (Chrome, Opera 15+) и WebKit (Safari). В вариантах с другими префиксами не существует. Попробуйте [SVG-маски](http://css.yoksel.ru/css-and-svg-masks/).

Comment: `-ms` - это IE, а у FF `-moz`. Впрочем, тут это не поможет, т. к. `mask-image` - это webkit'овское изобретение и больше его нигде нет.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте шейпы.  
Вот не плохая статья на эту тему. - 
http://frontender.info/css-shapes/

Делайте шейп картинки в нужной вам форме = resolved